# AWS API Gateway with Angular native $http service

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, http-headers, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have AWS API gateway that uses cognito temporary credentials. 
I want to setup angular native $http service to use api with required aws4 authentication headers. 
I tried to use https://github.com/mhart/aws4 but I'm getting `InvalidSignatureException`

Is there any way to generate aws4 auth headers for front-end applications? Does anyone have experience setting app API Gateway without autogenerated SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an angular module - [angular-aws-apig](https://github.com/jimmyn/angular-aws-apig) on top of [aws4](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) npm package. It provides an interceptor for `$http` service.

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-aws-apig'])
.config(function Config($httpProvider, APIGInterceptorProvider) {
    APIGInterceptorProvider.config({
        headers: {},
        region: 'us-east-1',
        service: 'execute-api',
        urlRegex: ''
    })

    /* @ngInject */
    APIGInterceptorProvider.headersGetter = function(myService, request) {
        myService.doSomething();
        return request.headers;
    };

    /* @ngInject */
    APIGInterceptorProvider.credentialsGetter = function(store, request) {
        return store.get('credentials');
    };

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIGInterceptor');
});
```

It allows to resolve **AWS IAM credentials** before the request. It could be handy to use with **AWS Cognito** or **Auth0** as they provide temporary IAM Credentials in exchange of user token. Those credentials then could be used to securely access APIGateway.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the aws4 library to work - it may be something in the way you are using it. If you can post some code it may help to diagnose.

The easiest way to integrate an API Gateway API is to use the generated JS SDK for your API. If you don't want to use it, you still may be able to re-use some of the SigV4 utilities in the generated SDK and integrate the signing process into your Angular client.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: generated JS SDK is ugly and buggy , for instance thay havent solved this bug - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=219537

Comment: Interesting - this was posted to the wrong forum. We will investigate. It is unfortunate that you had to jump through so many hoops to get the angular client working. For reference, the generated SDK is the official supported solution - if you have feedback or bug reports please let us know.